# Java: What is an alternative to using generics in this design?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

I'm working on an open-source Java library that will allow one to compute certain quantities, such as Gini index, of an attribute that takes on a finite number of values. (Formally, it computes the Gini index of the discrete distribution associated with the attribute `A`, but this is not relevant here.)

For example, one will be able to do the following

```
String[] namesArray = {"primary_school", "high_school", "university"};
Calculator<String> calc =new Calculator<String>(namesArray);

// p.getEducationLevel() returns `"primary_school"`, `"high_school"`, or `"university"`.
for (Person p : peopleCollection) {
    calc.increment(p.getEducationLevel());
}

// e.g. the Gini index of the distribution
double currentStat = calc.getCurrentValue();
```

The idea is to allow users of the library to use their own type to refer to attribute values; in this case, I am using strings (e.g. `"primary_school"`). But I might want to use integers or even my own type `AttributeValue`.

I solve this by defining

```
public class Calculator<T> {
    /* ... */
}
```

However, using generics causes some problems in the implementation: for example, if I want to maintain a collection of pairs of type `(T, double)`, I have to do nasty type casts:

```
public class Calculator<T>
        /* ... */
        private Queue<StreamElement<T>> slidingWindow;
        /* ... */
        class StreamElement<T> {
                private T label;
                private double value;

                StreamElement(T label, double value) {
                        this.label = label;
                        this.value = value;
                }

                public T getLabel() {
                        return label;
                }
                public double getValue() {
                        return value;
                }
        }
        /* ... */
            slidingWindow.add(new StreamElement<T>(label, value));
            if (slidingWindow.size() > windowSize) {
                    StreamElement lastElement = slidingWindow.remove();
                    // XXX: Nasty type cast
                    decrement((T)lastElement.getLabel(), lastElement.getValue());
            }
        /* ... */
}
```

Here is the warning produced by `javac`:

```
Calculator.java:163: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
            decrement((T)lastElement.getLabel(), lastElement.getValue());
                                             ^
  required: T
  found:    Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Calculator
1 warning
```

**Update.** If I do not do the type cast, I get

```
Calculator.java:163: error: no suitable method found for decrement(Object,double)
            decrement(lastElement.getLabel(), lastElement.getValue());
            ^
    method Calculator.decrement(T) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method Calculator.decrement(T,double) is not applicable
      (actual argument Object cannot be converted to T by method invocation conversion)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Calculator
1 error
```

Questions:

- What is a proper, clean way to do the type cast?
- What would be an alternative to using generics here?
- **More concretely, would it be better to instead define a class `Label` which user could extend to `MyLabel` and then use `MyLabel` for attribute values?** This means that `Calculator` would no longer be a generic type; in the implementation we'd have `class StreamElement { Label label; /* ... */ }` et cetera.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Here's a good tip for your generics: [Java PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: Well, it basically comes down to the question I linked, since you don't specify the type parameter here: `StreamElement lastElement`

Comment: Dear fabian, I believe the question is not a duplicate. I am asking what a Java expert would (advise me to) do in this specific case.

Comment: Which type is `slidingWindow` of?

Comment: It says in the code above: `private Queue<StreamElement<T>> slidingWindow;` It's instantiated as `ArrayDeque<StreamElement<T>>`

Comment: bummer ;-) you're right I'm blind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just made some mistake.

This is the correct implementation:

```
        /* ... */
            slidingWindow.add(new StreamElement<T>(label, value));
            if (slidingWindow.size() > windowSize) {
                    // Don't forget the generic argument at StreamElement
                    StreamElement<T> lastElement = slidingWindow.remove();
                    decrement(lastElement.getLabel(), lastElement.getValue());
            }
        /* ... */
```

Comment: Okay, I tried to simplify the question and I didn't mention that I am implementing a generic interface. So `decrement` is defined as part of an interface `Interface<T>` which `Calculator<T>` implements. See the error I get (see update to the answer). I don't know whether this makes a difference---I am inexperienced in Java.

Comment: Ah... this is embarrassing. I didn't notice I was missing the generic argument.

Comment: It's okay, I deserved it. :) It's ironic I wrote a whole post wihout noticing it.